# Video Emulation solution

Tags: h.264, video-capture

For a professional application I'm using a video grabber to capture realtime the video output of a PC, having various resolutions (Full HD to 4K) and incapsulate it into a RTP stream with RTSP signalling protocol toward a video recorder. The codec used for video is H.264

I Need your help because i want to emulate many of these devices working simultaneously.

The First approach i would use is to search for a demux that Is capable to receive as input one real stream and replicate It on many output streams.
The second approach Is to find a software emulator of h.264 video over RTP.

In both cases i have no idea what to search on the shelf.

Comment: You might get a faster Answer by asking [**SuperUser**](https://superuser.com). While you wait... You can try downloading FFmpeg for your OS. It will mux/encode into multiple outputs. Not sure about _"software emulator of h.264 video over RTP"_. All I can tell you is that FFmpeg can output to an RTP server (even if local), it also has FFplay which can display from RTP. Maybe those two things can be used together? Maybe explain what emulation should achieve (eg: I just want to see output RTP packet (bytes) structure? or... I want a decoder to display (pixel) frames from my new RTP output).

Comment: Your grabber has already a rtsp Server, is there a limit how many streams you can get from, when yes you just need an rtsp Proxy Server there are some of them around like mediamtx.